# Laravel seeder with Eloquent give timestamp null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to insert static data, with the help of the seeder and Eloquent as bellow.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;

class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Role::insert(array(
            array('name' => 'admin'),
            array('name' => 'user')
        ));
    }
}
```

Even after using Eloquent i am getting timestamp null in database.

Comment: Check your model and database field type

Comment: The `insert` method doesn't insert the timestamps. Use `create` instead `insert`, or manually add the timestamps fields.

Comment: Yes with create timestamps works @porloscerrosΨ. Thanks.

Comment: Great. @STA answer illustrate and explain better what I was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` columns (*created_at* and *updated_at*) will be assigned automatically only if you are using the **Eloquent**
`save()` method and `create` method are **Eloquent**.
While `insert` method is **not Eloquent**, it's a query builder method. So use `create` method instead :

```
public function run()
    {
        Role::create(array(
            array('name' => 'admin'),
            array('name' => 'user')
        ));
    }
```

When you are using query builder, you have to `created_at` and `updated_at` value by yourself :

```
Role::insert(array(
  array('name' => 'admin'),
  array('name' => 'user'),
  array('created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()),
  array('updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;
class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Role::truncate();
        Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
        Role::create(['name' => 'user']);
    }
}
```

The error is generated because you are using insert instead of create.